# Binary Search Tree insertion in Python not returning to console

Tags: python, python-3.x, insert, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

while learning about BSTs in hackerrank, I came across the following issue.

My classes for the Node and for the Binary Search Tree is defined as follows:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,info):
        self.info = info
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self,val):
        currentNode = self.root
        if currentNode is None:
            self.root = Node(val)
        elif currentNode.info > val:
            currentNode.left = insert(currentNode.left,val)
        elif currentNode.info < val:
            currentNode.right = insert(currentNode.right,val)
        return currentNode
```

However, performing a traversal on `tree = BinarySearchTree()` after using `tree.insert(arr[i]` over a for loop for some array of integers `arr` returns no output. The logic seems correct to me, and I suspect that this is due to a difference in type between Node and BST, but I am unsure of how to resolve this.

Edit: below is the full code from hackerrank. The only bit I was able to edit is the insert function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, info):
        self.info = info  
        self.left = None  
        self.right = None 
        self.level = None 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.info) 

def preOrder(root):
    if root == None:
        return
    print (root.info, end=" ")
    preOrder(root.left)
    preOrder(root.right)
    
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.root = None

    def insert(self,val):
        currentNode = self.root
        if currentNode is None:
            self.root = Node(val)
        elif currentNode.info > val:
            currentNode.left = insert(currentNode.left,val)
        elif currentNode.info < val:
            currentNode.right = insert(currentNode.right,val)
        return currentNode

tree = BinarySearchTree()
t = int(input())

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

for i in range(t):
    tree.insert(arr[i])

preOrder(tree.root)
```

The given test case was

```
6
4 2 3 1 7 6
```

and was supposed to return `4 2 3 1 7 6`, but no output was returned.

Edit: made the changes according to the first answer! Now, I have the following week error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File “solution.py”, line 40, in <module>
        tree.insert(arr[i])
    File “solution.py”, line 30, in insert
        currentNode.left = insert(currentNode.left,val)
NameError: name ‘insert’ is not defined
```

Comment: Can you also post your test cases and your expected result?

Comment: @jshamble alright!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to

```
    def insert(self, val, currentNode):

        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(val)

        elif currentNode.info > val:
            if currentNode.left is None
                currentNode.left = Node(val)
            else:
                self.insert(val, currentNode.left)

        elif currentNode.info < val:

            if currentNode.right is None
                currentNode.right = Node(val)
            else:
                self.insert(val, currentNode.right)
```

and call it via

```
 tree.insert(val,tree.root)
```

Comment: Thank you! What were the other issues with my original code? :)

Comment: if it works kindly upvote the answer :) there a few logic issues, along with you trying to call the insert function, without the use of `self.function()`

Comment: I have accepted it as the answer, but sadly I do not have the required reputation for my upvote to be public :( may I ask why the additional conditions are necessary? Say if I reach a child node, wouldn’t the self.root if condition insert Node(val) there?

Comment: firstly the issue with that is that you have the folowing code

`elif currentNode.info > val:
        currentNode.left = insert(currentNode.left,val)`

you do not have a function that accepts a Node, you only have the insert function that accepts the val parameter, so that is a syntactical error, secondly, the first line of the function is `currentNode = self.root` if you were to pass a currentNode argument, you are defaulting it again to self.root, so it will always be stuck in an infinite loop, thats a semantic error :)

Comment: hello, now I obtain name ‘self’ is not defined in the line with def insert(), is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem lies here

```
def insert(self,val):
    currentNode = self.root
    if currentNode is None:
        currentNode = Node(val)
    elif currentNode.info > val:
        currentNode.left = insert(currentNode.left,val)
    elif currentNode.info < val:
        currentNode.right = insert(currentNode.right,val)
    return currentNode
```

as you can see you do "insert" the node but you dont assign it, the code block

```
if currentNode is None:
    currentNode = Node(val)
```

should be

```
if currentNode is None:
    self.root = Node(val)
```

you keep on trying to traverse a Null tree

EDIT: Its possible that this is not the problem, please provide the full code the `create()` function is missing from your code but is called

Comment: Hi, create was a typo, should have been insert!

Comment: in that case, this is the issue, you create a node when the root is empty but dont store it anywhere, this should resolve the problem :)

Comment: Hello, after the edit, now I get NameError: name ‘insert’ is not defined :(

Comment: Edited following your answer!

Comment: could you also please post the error? where does it exactly give that error, etc.

Comment: oh ok, i think i got the error in your code, let me explain

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat shorter version which avoids nested "if" statements and without the "Node" class:

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.info = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self,val):
        if self.info is None:
            self.info = val
            self.left = BinarySearchTree()
            self.right = BinarySearchTree()
        elif self.info > val:
            self.left.insert(val)
        elif self.info < val:
            self.right.insert(val)
```